# Sort in Get-ADComputer

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm not good at powershell, so I ask the community for help.
The task is to filter the Get-ADComputer output by different files. Sort by Property IPv4Address. In the file itself, you need to see all objects with sorted IPv4Address + Measure-Object output.
Example.\

```
SAD-MAZINA                                                                                          192.168.8.172                                                                                      
SAD-DISPETCHER                                                                                      192.168.8.173                                                                                      
SAD-POHORSKA                                                                                        192.168.8.179                                                                                      
SAD-PROPUSKA                                                                                        192.168.8.181                                                                                      
SAD-DERADMIN1                                                                                       192.168.8.182                                                                                      
SAD-LIZUNKINA                                                                                       192.168.8.184                                                                                      
SAD-CHEGLAKOV                                                                                       192.168.8.33                                                                                       
184-DSKTP                                                                                           192.168.8.34                                                                                       
LAPTOP-1                                                                                            192.168.8.35                                                                                       
SAD-MAKAROVA                                                                                        192.168.8.50
All                                                                                                 10
```

At first I tried to implement it myself using **foreach** and **if** construct, but there is not enough knowledge to complete the task. Any help, thanks!
Example.\

```
$regex = [Regex]"192.168.0.*"

$scan = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -ResultPageSize 0 -Prop CN,lastLogonTimestamp,IPv4Address |
Where {[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp) -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | Sort-Object -Property IPv4Address | FT CN,IPv4Address
foreach ($onepc in $scan){

if ($onepc = $regex){
out-file -filepath C:\comps192.168.csv
}
}
```

Comment: And what is your question? What problem do you have with your code?

Comment: [1] `=` is an **assignment** and should not be used as comparison operator. [2] remove `| FT CN,IPv4Address` because that is just for outputting to console. [3] You intend to loop over a set of computer **objects** but ignore to test the property `IPv4Address`. If you do, you can test it with the `-like` operator, since you define the IP to test against with a wildcard anyway. [4] you output nothing to the file..

Comment: @marsze 
the problem is that my script simply displays a list of all active PCs to the console, but it needs to be sorted by ip addresses and by different files.

Comment: @Theo Thanks for the clarification 1 and 2 ok corrected. 3, the like operator is not quite suitable for me, since it is precisely the subnets of the 192.168.0.0/24 or 10.20.0.0/24 type that need to be isolated according to different files.

Comment: Please see my edit to test if the IPv4Address is inside a given subnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, there is quite a few things wrong with your code.

You are defining a regex, where it really is a wildcard string. Later on you compare IP addresses to this "regex" with the assignment operator `=`

By using `| FT CN,IPv4Address`, your variable $scan will contain a string array, not an array of objects you need for creating a valid CSV file

Try

```
$ipRange = "192.168.0.*"
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date  # set time part to all 0, so this date is midnight
$scan = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties CN,LastLogonDate,IPv4Address |
        Where {$_.LastLogonDate -ge $refDate -and $_.IPv4Address -like $ipRange} | 
        Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {[int]($_.IPv4Address.Split(".")[-1])}}

# output to console
$scan | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$scan | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\comps192.168.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>The line `Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {[int]($_.IPv4Address.Split(".")[-1])}}` uses a calculated property to sort on. In this case the integer value of the last IP addresses octet. That way, IP `192.186.0.2` will be sorted before `192.168.0.11`, whereas if you sort on the ip **strings** the result would be the other way around.

Also, with Get-ADComputer, you can ask for property `LastLogonDate`, which is the value of `lastLogonTimeStamp` already converted to a (local) DateTime object.</sup>

---

**Edit**

If, as you commented, your aim is to test if the IP address is inside a certain subnet, you could make use of below helper function

```
function Test-IsIPv4InSubnet ([string]$IpAndCidr, [string]$IpAddress) {
    $network, [int]$subnetlen = $IpAndCidr.Split('/')
    $a = [uint32[]]$network.split('.')
    [uint32] $unetwork = ($a[0] -shl 24) + ($a[1] -shl 16) + ($a[2] -shl 8) + $a[3]

    $subnetlen = [Math]::Min([Math]::Max([Math]::Abs($subnetlen), 0), 32)
    $mask = (-bnot [uint32]0) -shl (32 - $subnetlen)

    $a = [uint32[]]$IpAddress.split('.')
    [uint32] $uip = ($a[0] -shl 24) + ($a[1] -shl 16) + ($a[2] -shl 8) + $a[3]

    return ($unetwork -eq ($mask -band $uip))
}
```

With that in place on top of your script, the code can be like:

```
$ipSubnet = "192.168.0.0/24"
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date  # set time part to all 0, so this date is midnight
$scan = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties CN,LastLogonDate,IPv4Address |
        Where {$_.LastLogonDate -ge $refDate -and (Test-IsIPv4InSubnet $ipSubnet $_.IPv4Address)} | 
        Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {[int]($_.IPv4Address.Split(".")[-1])}}

# output to console
$scan | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to CSV
$scan | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\comps192.168.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```